# N-tier web server with an n-tier business server

Tags: c#, asp.net, n-tier-architecture

Architectually, do you need a n-tier ASP.net MVC web server when you have a separate n-tier business server to connect to for logic processing?

Is there any other reasons to use the n-tier architecture for the web server besides separation of business logic?
Would it make sense for the data layer to be handled by the business server also?

To me it seems like the web server has no need for the n-tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no application that can not fit into 1-tier. So in theory You do not need multi-tier everywhere.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658103.aspx):

> Decide if you need a separate business layer. It is always a good idea to use a separate business layer where possible to improve the maintainability of your application. The exception may be applications that have few or no business rules (other than data validation).

You may have different reasons to add extra layer and that may be for example:

- reuse and maintainability
- coupling and cohesion
- traceability
- caching
- scaleability
- security

All depends on specific needs. So You need to know Your trade offs.

Also good to know from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998478.aspx):

> A layer is a logical structuring mechanism for the elements that make up your software solution; a tier is a physical structuring mechanism for the system infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

*When and if* you already have dedicated app-server, you don't need n-tier inside web application, because your web application is (should by) only presentation layer over existing business layer.

BTW, are you sure you're not confusing layers and tiers?